# adding code snippet to Razor (MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I read the docs and apparently this should be acceptable:

```
    @{
    string isDisplay = "";    
    if (@ViewBag.Name == "" || @ViewBag.Name == null)
    { 
        isDisplay ="display:none;";
    }
}
```

it's giving me a compliation error however though:

this is the error:
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the compiler on hand, but this should be better

```
   @{
    string isDisplay = "";    
    if (ViewBag.Name == "" || ViewBag.Name == null)
    { 
        isDisplay ="display:none;";
    }
```

No need for the @ sign in a Razor Block

Comment: still getting the same compilation error. the row that's highlighted is the first @{

Comment: turns out it didn't work inside my custom form html helper method...when I put the code outside, it worked fine.  Thanks for the help.